# Merge a column with results from an ActiveRecord query in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have the three following tables in Ruby on Rails 4:

The "Decision" table:

```
class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :colour,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_many :decision_datafields, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :datafields, through: :decision_datafields 

    def datafields
        Datafield.where(id: self.decision_datafields.select("datafield_id"))
    end 
end
```

The "DecisionDatafield" table (linking table):

```
class DecisionDatafield < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :min_score, presence: true
    validates_inclusion_of :min_score, :in => 1..10
    belongs_to :decision
    belongs_to :datafield
end
```

The "Datafield" table:

```
class Datafield < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_many :decision_datafields, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :decisions, through: :decision_datafields  
    has_many :score_options, dependent: :destroy

    def decisions
        Decision.where(id: self.decision_datafields.select("decision_id"))
    end
end
```

There is also a score options table, but it isn't necessary for the problem.

Anyway, what I'd like to be able to do is do a query like this:

```
Decision.first.datafields
```

... and have ActiveRecord retrieve a list of the first Decision's Datafields, along with the corresponding min_score value from the DecisionDatafields linking table.

Right now, the above query will return something like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Datafield id: 1, title: "DF1", created_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26", updated_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26">, #<Datafield id: 2, title: "DF2", created_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26", updated_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26">]>
```

... which is nice, but I want it to look like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Datafield id: 1, title: "DF1", created_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26", updated_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26", min_score: 5>, #<Datafield id: 2, title: "DF2", created_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26", updated_at: "2015-03-28 09:59:26, min_score: 7">]>
```

The difference is that the min_score from the DecisionDatafield linking table has been joined to the records returned by the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might work (haven't tested it):

```
class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def data_fields
    Datafield.includes(:decision_datafield).select("datafields.*, decision_datafields.min_score").where(id: self.decision_datafields.select("datafield_id"))
  end
end
```

Call it with `Decision.first.data_fields`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it returns the same thing as the original queries.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like the `datafields` method is not being called, and instead the default active record relationship is being used. Try changing the method name to `data_fields`; I updated the answer.

Comment: I'm currently using this in the console:

    `Datafield.includes(:decision_datafields).select("datafields.*, decision_datafields.min_score").where(id: d.decision_datafields.select("datafield_id")).first`

It's still not appending the 'min_score' value to the returned records, however.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following works:

```
Datafield.where(id: self.decision_datafields.select("datafield_id")).includes(:decision_datafields).joins("left join decision_datafields on datafields.id = decision_datafields.datafield_id").select("datafields.*, decision_datafields.min_score as min_score")
```

It would appear, however, that when using the Rails console, the min_score does not get added to the record.

However, calling `Decision.first.datafields.first.min_score` does return a value (it's just not shown when viewing the record via `Decision.first.datafields.first`.